# How to connect to a remote sinopia?

Tags: sinopia

**Problem**

Sinopia cannot be accessed remotely, while it is possible to access it from the same box.

**Attempts to solve the issue**

/vagrant/sinopia/config.yaml

```
# path to a directory with all packages
listen: 0.0.0.0:10000
```

sinopia is started:

```
vagrant@sinopia:/vagrant$ sinopia 
 warn  --- config file  - /vagrant/sinopia/config.yaml
 warn  --- http address - http://0.0.0.0:10000/
```

the port is listening:

```
vagrant@sinopia:~$ ss -nat | grep 10000
LISTEN     0      128          *:10000                    *:*
```

but telnet

```
telnet 192.168.10.20 10000
```

fails

```
Trying 192.168.10.20...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.10.20: Connection refused
```

there is also no firewall

```
vagrant@sinopia:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I have found this unanswered question

https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=120253

The issue persists when [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) is deployed.

**Question**

How to connect to a remote sinopia?

Comment: I see you posted an [issue on the verdaccio repo](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/issues/82). This is good since this is the maintained fork, but your code indicates the older sinopia package. Are you actually using verdaccio?

Comment: @scniro I have tried to solve the issue using verdaccio but the issue persists

Comment: Can you post the output of "ip addr show"? Just to make sure that "192.168.10.20" is actually assigned to the machine you're running the telnet command on?

Comment: Could you update your question and add an example that prove does not work with Docker verdaccio? I've been testing and I have access to the docker container whether you expose properly the ports.